# how to start ie browser using capybara for my web app testing with cucumber testing

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I have done IE browser launching through Watir and I want to know how to launch IE browser using capybara with cucumber framework.
If you provide me how to launch using env.rb file then it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :internet_explorer)
end
```

?

Answer (score 0):

And you need ie driver in your path.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list